# UIWebView with -webkit-translated elements screenshot

Tags: objective-c, ipad, screenshot

I have a UIWebView, which contains some elements that look like this:

```
<div class="bbib wbg rect" id="rect" style="-webkit-transform: perspective(100px) translate3d(6px, 63px, -48px) rotateY(-106deg); ">
</div>
```

I need to take a screenshot of this webview (it's fullsize, for iPad, 1024x768), but when I use

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return screenshot;
```

(this code is in UIView category), the elements on the image are located at their original positions (no translations/rotations).
That's not good.

How can it be solved?